# Site already on Cloudflare, how much additional benefit I obtain using an external image CDN service

Tags: node.js, image-processing, cloudflare, cdn

l have a question.

Context: I'm using hetzner cloud using volume named "`new_volume`" mounted in same server.

My website is in nodeJS and already using Cloudflare, so, I obtain the benefics of CDN around the world.
The images on my site are already optimize by the use of internal scripts, well, not totally optimize, they are just resize and exported with a low quality in different sizes for differents locations in the site, I'm not using .webp images, only.jpg and .png images.
All the image are save in the volume `/mnt/new_volume/data`.

Cloudflare right now is caching the image that comes from my "new_volume", these images can be considered local because are in the same server, just like store .css and .js files, but, for images the difference is that are stored in `/mnt/new_volume/data`. In fact i'm using symlinks to store files in `/mnt`  and then creating symlinks in website root folder

My question is; If I use any image CDN to store and optimize image to deliver me a new url with propper parameters per image, this will made to load faster the image through image CDN service or will be almost the same as my local stored images?

Note: I know that cloudflare have a image service but I don't wanna use it.

Thanks.

I'm thinking that storing image in external CDN while the site is already on CDN is redundant and i'm actually losing some ms in loading, I don't know.